# How to pass a value to a subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Im having trouble passing a value to a subquery in MySQL, for what i have read this is not possible in MySQL, but i cant manage to find anotherway to do this query.

the value to pass is "pnl_partsA.part_image" from the first part of the query.
What Im tying to obtain is the part_image that is present in more than one manufacturer.

```
SELECT manufacturer, chapter, part_image
FROM pnl_parts pnl_partsA
WHERE 1 = 1
AND part_image <> ''
#AND manufacturer = 'fiat'
#AND part_image = 'F01A050'
AND (   SELECT COUNT(chapter)
        FROM (  SELECT manufacturer, chapter, part_image
                FROM pnl_parts
                WHERE part_image = pnl_partsA.part_image
                AND part_image <> ''
                AND manufacturer = pnl_partsA.manufacturer
                GROUP BY manufacturer, chapter, part_image
             )  chaptercount 
    )  > 1
ORDER BY part_image
;
```

Adding more information...
What I need to get are the chapters that have a duplicate part_image

[image]

any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Which value do you want to pass to the subquery?

Comment: To a rough approximation, you're never going to find `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same query. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: yes thanks i corrected that

Comment: You are trying to do a [correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) which is supported by mysql. If you can share some sample data and what you are wanting as a desired result we can help with a rewrite that might make more sense for what you need.

Comment: I added an example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the `manufacturer` and `part_image` group(s), which has more than one rows, using `Group By` and `Having COUNT(*) > 1`. We will use this result-set in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and Join to the main table, to get the relevant row(s):

Try the following query instead:

```
SELECT 
  pp1.manufacturer, 
  pp1.chapter, 
  pp1.part_image 
FROM pnl_parts AS pp1
JOIN (
       SELECT 
         pp2.manufacturer, 
         pp2.part_image 
       FROM pnl_parts AS pp2 
       WHERE pp2.part_image <> ''
       GROUP BY 
         pp2.manufacturer, 
         pp2.part_image
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) AS dt 
  ON dt.manufacturer = pp1.manufacturer AND 
     dt.part_image = pp1.part_image
```